# How to remove the box from a checkbox control

Tags: java, css, javafx

Goal: Remove the box from a check-box node in JavaFX so that only the check-box label is displayed.

I need to have the 'selected' functionality of the node, so using a button or label in place of it would not work.

I made the box invisible and removed any insets, but there was still a gap behind the check box label.

```
.check-box .box {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-padding: 0;
}
```

Since the box is a component of a region, I tried setting the max width and height of the box to zero. This had no affect.

```
    -fx-max-height: 0;
    -fx-max-width: 0;
```

Attempting to remove the box shape, again having no affect:

```
    -fx-shape: none;
```

Comment: It's not really clear what the requirement is here. If you don't want to see the check box at all, why not just use a label along with a boolean variable indicating whether or not it is selected?

Comment: @James_D Apologies for being vague. I'm using numerous check boxes, so if I were to replace each one with a label, I'd need a data structure to hold the labels as well as relate them to their boolean value. It would work, but I figure using check boxes is simpler and more concise.

Comment: In anything other than quick throwaway test code, you should be storing the state of your application separately from the UI (i.e. using a MVC/MVP/MVVM type design), so presumably you are already creating such a data structure anyway. And since you ended up posting here, clearly your suggested approach isn't simpler and more concise.

Comment: This still sounds very weird though. You want the state of the application to change in response to user action (the user clicking on the checkbox/label), but you want no visual feedback to the user indicating whether the state is selected or not? That just sounds like a horrible user experience, however you implement it.

Comment: @James_D The check box label is highlighted upon selection; I think it looks better than having a box beside it. I just want to remove the box, if possible. If not, then I'll resort to using only labels.

Comment: *"The check box label is highlighted upon selection; I think it looks better than having a box beside it."* This sounds like a `ToggleButton`. That would at least seem like a better starting point than a `CheckBox` for what you describe.

Answer (score 4):

From the comments:

> The check box label is highlighted upon selection; I think it looks better than having a box beside it.

This combined with the original description of having a control with the functionality of being selected, without the check box but with selection being depicted by a change in color is exactly what is offered by a [`ToggleButton`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ToggleButton.html).

Here is a quick demo of several toggle buttons:

```
public class Toggles extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        for (int i = 1 ; i <=10 ; i++) {
            root.getChildren().add(new ToggleButton("Choice "+i));
        }
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

which looks like

[image]

(here Choice 3 and Choice 4 are selected; Choice 4 additionally has focus).

If you want to style these to look more like labels with highlighting for the selected ones, you can add a stylesheet with something like

```
.toggle-button {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-background;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-background-color;
}

.toggle-button:selected {
    -fx-background: -fx-accent;
}
```

which results in

[image]

If you really want to do this with check boxes, something like

```
.check-box {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-background ;
    -fx-label-padding: 0;
}

.check-box > .box, .check-box > .box > .mark {
    -fx-padding: 0 ;
}

.check-box:selected {
    -fx-background: -fx-accent ;
}
```

works.